# Installing Devise Gem: forcing your application to not access the DB or load models when precompiling assets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hi guys I am running through a tutorial where we are installing the Devise Gem. On one of the steps we are told to include this code:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in our `config/application.rb` file

After doing this when I try to get help on my generator command by passing --help I get this error message:

```
$ rails generate devise --help
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
c:/Users/Javi/Desktop/rails_projects/reddit_on_rails/config/application.rb:4:in
`<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
(NameError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

If I remove the previous peice of code from the `config/application.rb` file then I can pass the --help command to generate devise with no problem. I am not able to decipher the error message. Any ideas as to what happened and if it will be an issue moving forwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the generator with:

`rails generate devise:install`

and then you run `rails generate devise User` to add Devise to your existing User class (assuming it's named that).

`rails generate devise --help` just lists the options for the devise generator.